# Making Django model Query case-insensitive

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I would like to look up users by their email without worrying about uppercase letters.

How would I do this?  I tried

```
customer = Customer.objects.get(email__lower="test@gmail.com")
```

and got this error.

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'lower' for EmailField or join on the field not permitted.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work with the [**`__iexact`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iexact):

```
customer = Customer.objects.get(email__iexact='test@gmail.com')
```

Contrary to popular belief, calling lowercase over two items does *not* check if the two match in a case insensitive way. Some characters have no lowercase/uppercase variant, for example [*ß* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F). In order to determine if two strings match case-insensitive, one should apply a [*case folding* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Case_folding).